# Error 1001: While Installing the windows service in a machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

We have developed one windows service using C#.NET. While installing the service in a system we are facing the issue says, Error 1001: No Mapping between Account names and security Ids was done.

We have tried setting the properties of 'ServiceProcessInstaller' account to LocalSystem and Starttype as Automatic. And still the issue is not resolved.

Also tried changing in Registry path, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GPExtensions{827D319E-6EAC-11D2-A4EA-00C04F79F83A} - ExtensionDebuglevel value to 0 as well as 2, but same issue persist.

Please suggest any solutions for the same.

Comment: A service by default runs with a System Account that does not have an environment.  Try starting service using a Service Account instead of the default System Account.